# Call method in navigationController's rootViewController from a 3rd ViewController in the stack - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

my `navigationControllers` hierarchy is like:

vc1 -> vc2 -> vc3

I want to call a vc1 method from vc3, at the time of vc3 dismissal.

I tried to implement delegates but since vc1 doesn't have a vc3 object, it didn't work.

(vc3 is created at the time of `segue` from vc2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to implement delegates but since vc1 doesn't have a vc3
>   object, it didn't work.

Yes, but when you create v3 in scope of v2's lifecycle, you have access to both v1 and v3 (I suppose, you can link v1 and v3 together in `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`).
Update: Try using self.navigationController.viewControllers[0] to retrieve vc1.

Comment: I basically want to do this: `vc3.delegate = self; //vc1` , but this cannot be done in vc1 class since there's no vc3 object.

Following what you said, I tried this in vc2's `prepareForSegue` : `vc2.delegate = self.parentViewController;`
but no luck, still delegate method is not called in vc1 :(

Comment: You didn't manage to link those up together because self.parentViewController is nil. Try using self.navigationController.viewControllers[0] to retrieve vc1.

Comment: Also, can you please tell me why `self.parentViewController` is nil ? Isn't vc1 the parent of vc2? :S does `parentViewController` mean the actual `navigationController` and not the `viewControllers` in it ?

Comment: Sure, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/parentViewController first. The parent view controller is involved into parent-children VC hierarchies, not in predecessor-successor ones.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91824/discussion-between-arthur-gevorkyan-and-sha).

Answer (score 0):

try this code : 
create three viewcontrollers 
ViewController1
ViewController2
ViewController3

//ViewController1.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "ViewController2.h"
    #import "ViewController3.h"


    @interface ViewController1 : UIViewController <callDelegate>

    @end
```

//ViewController1.m

```
#import "ViewController1.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController1 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    ViewController3 *v3=[[ViewController3 alloc]init];
    v3.mydelegate=self;


    ViewController2 *v2=[[ViewController2 alloc]init];
    v2.myView=v3;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:v2 animated:YES];


    UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
lbl.text=@"v1";



}

-(void)delegateCalled{
    NSLog(@"I am V1");
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

//ViewController2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController3.h"


@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController 
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIViewController *myView;
@end
```

//ViewController2.m

```
#import "ViewController2.h"
#import "ViewController3.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2 

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

//    ViewController3 *v3=[[ViewController3 alloc]init];
//   self.myView.mydelegate=self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.myView animated:YES];


    UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

    lbl.text=@"V2";

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

//ViewController3.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol callDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)delegateCalled;

@end
@interface ViewController3 : UIViewController 
@property(nonatomic,weak)id<callDelegate>mydelegate;

@end
```

//ViewController3.m

```
#import "ViewController3.h"

@interface ViewController3 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController3

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIButton *lbl=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [lbl setTitle:@"v3" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [lbl addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.mydelegate delegateCalled];

}

-(void)buttonClick{
    [self.mydelegate delegateCalled];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Answer has been provided already. Please read entire post (Question and Answer(if available), then add your answers. Thanks!